# Play streaming video after buffering completed MPMovieViewController

Tags: ios, video-streaming, mpmovieplayercontroller

Is there any way to buffer/download the video first then play the video without stall with MPMovieViewController?

Here is my code

```
player =[[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc]initWithContentURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];

[player.moviePlayer setControlStyle:MPMovieControlStyleFullscreen];
player.moviePlayer.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeStreaming;
[self presentViewController:player animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this method

> // Indicates if a movie should automatically start playback when it is likely to finish uninterrupted based on e.g. network conditions. Defaults to YES.

```
@property(nonatomic) BOOL shouldAutoplay;
```